# Elixir generates a url with "?" instead of "/"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this route:

```
    resources "/my_items", ItemController, only: [:index, :show]
    get "/pages/:page_number", ItemController, :page, param: "page_number"
```

I have actions in `ItemController` for `pages`, it's a simplified version:

```
def index(conn, p) do
  # .....


def page(conn, %{"page_number" => page_num) when is_nil(page_num) do
  index(conn, %{"page_number" => 1})
end

def page(conn, %{"page_number" => page_num) do
  index(conn, %{"page_number" => page_num})
end
```

When I go to "/pages/123", it works fine. However, this:

```
items_path(conn, :page, page_number:  456)
```

throws an exception:

```
protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for [page_number: 456]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect to get a map (basically, a `Phoenix.Param` to be converted to a map there):

```
#          ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
page(conn, %{"page_number" => page_num ...
```

and what you are passing there is a [`Keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#content), that is attempted to be [converted to a `Param`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/param.ex#L75). Since you already declared the param name, just do:

```
items_path(conn, :page, 456)
```

---

*Sidenote:* your `page` declarations are not valid Elixir code: closing curly brace is required there.